# HtmlDocument Body is Nothing when setting InnerHTML

Tags: vb.net, dom

I'm having an irritating issue with my code.

I need to find a way to initialize the Body property of the HTMLDocument object.

```
Dim helpContent As XmlDocument

Sub LoadDocument()
  Dim sectionNode As Xml.XmlNode
  Dim HtmlDoc As HtmlDocument = Nothing
  Dim details As String

  ' The WebBrowser1.Document is loaded from an XML document in Resources
  HtmlDoc = WebBrowser1.Document
  sectionNode = helpContent.SelectSingleNode("//TitlePage")

  lblSectionHeader.Text = IIf(title Is Nothing, "Title Page", title)

  Dim detailsNode As Xml.XmlNode
  detailsNode = sectionNode.SelectSingleNode("ContentDetails")
  details = detailsNode.InnerText
  details = Replace(details, "[HELPPATH]", G.HelpPath)

  HtmlDoc.Body.InnerHtml = details
```

At this point Body is NOTHING and the assignation fails with Error 91
"Object variable OR With block variable NOT set"

```
  WebBrowser1.DocumentText = HtmlDoc.Body.InnerHtml
End Sub
```

If I repeat the loop twice and go through my error logging routine, the body suddenly becomes assigned.

I've tried finding a way of initializing the Body object, but it's ReadOnly

Does anyone know of a way I can stop this happening?

Comment: Has the browser managed to finish loading the document properly before this code runs?  Perhaps after whatever your loop is runs twice, it's had time to finish loading the document?

Comment: I've got a loop
    ---- While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While ----

which completes before it ever gets to this stage, so I'd say Yes.

Comment: I also added in a ---- HtmlDoc.Title = title ---- That now fails with: "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component", really helpful!